# How to schedule a node.js script execution in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an app running in `Heroku` free servers. There I have setup a node.js script that I am calling from my android app. Now I need to execute a script in a timed fashion. I did some googling on that and found that it can be done by two ways `Process Scheduler` add-on and a `Task-Scheduler` add-on.

I probably want to call a link in my app that will execute some node.js code. I am not sure whether I should use `Process Scheduler` or a `Task Scheduler` for the job. Also in their docs they have mentioned how to use them for Ruby ,  Scala and stuff. But I just need to call an URL from my app. How can that be done and will it cost me or can it be done in this free hosting itself?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you intend to run your script at a particular time (schedule it) or when a user interacts with your app? How does the app interaction work?

Comment: The script should run once every 10 minutes. It will be checking if a notification should be sent the user. It is going to interact with my DB and get the time and if the time is nearby the current time a notification will be sent.

Comment: @Chris. Please see my response above

Comment: What does "I probably want to call a link in my app that will execute some node.js code." mean? Do you want the application to act as if somebody visits a particular URL every 10 minutes? Generally admin tasks should be written as command-line scripts so you can just run them. That's not Heroku-specific; it's how Cron works too.